# how to automatically call the textDidChange method of UITextField in iphone app

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield

I am working in iphone app in which there is textfield i want that when any text is changed then following method should call automatically.

```
   -(void)textFieldTextDidChangeOneCI:(UITextField*)tf{



NSLog(@"Testing Successful Value %.2f",appDelegate.p_ClinInf_Yes_V_InModel);
appDelegate.p_ClinInf_Yes_NV_InModel  = [[textFieldOne text] floatValue];

appDelegate.p_ClinInf_No_NV_InModel=100-appDelegate.p_ClinInf_Yes_NV_InModel;

textFieldTwo.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",appDelegate.p_ClinInf_No_NV_InModel];


NSCharacterSet * set = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789."] invertedSet];
NSString*string=textFieldOne.text;
if ([string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:set].location != NSNotFound) {
    UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"Only a number can be entered into this input field " delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
    textFieldOne.text=@"";


}

NSLog(@"Testing Successful CI Data  %.2f",appDelegate.p_ClinInf_Yes_NV_InModel);

}
```

currently i am calling this

using

```
    [textFieldOne addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldTextDidChangeOneCI:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 addObserver:self
 selector:@selector(textFieldTextDidChangeOneCI:)
 name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification
 object:textfield];
 }
```

Also modify your method

```
 -(void)textFieldTextDidChangeOneCI:(NSNotification *)notification
 {
UITextField *textfield=[notification object];
NSLog(@"%@",textfield.text);

 }
```

Comment: where to write this in viewDidLoad

Comment: can call two methods on same textfield

Comment: is it possible two call two different methods for same textfield and it mean that if text is changes then it will call two methods or any of the one

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this one

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
   [self textFieldTextDidChangeOneCI:textField];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: on which textfield this will be called

Comment: i have 4 textfields with different methods to call by default

Comment: You can run a conditional check on the textField checking if its equal to a member in the view controller

Answer (score 0):

you can do like below

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(textDidChange:) name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

let me know it is working or not

Answer (score 0):

You can add observer for the UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification which will be posted whenever the text changes in text field.

See the below code for example :

```
// For textField1
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
addObserver:self 
   selector:@selector(anyMethod:)
       name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification 
     object:textField1];

// For textField2
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
addObserver:self 
   selector:@selector(anyMethod:)
       name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification 
     object:textField2];
```